# What is the "parent" parameter in Google Cloud Translate Advanced (V3)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, webkit, google-translate, node-webkit

Google Translate API v3 requires us to pass the "parent" parameter.

It's everywhere on their sample code, such as :

```js
/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment these variables before running the sample.
 */
// const projectId = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID';
// const location = 'global';
// const text = 'text to translate';

// Imports the Google Cloud Translation library
const {TranslationServiceClient} = require('@google-cloud/translate');

// Instantiates a client
const translationClient = new TranslationServiceClient();
async function translateText() {
  // Construct request
  const request = {
    parent: `projects/${projectId}/locations/${location}`, // <-- HERE
    contents: [text],
    mimeType: 'text/plain', // mime types: text/plain, text/html
    sourceLanguageCode: 'en',
    targetLanguageCode: 'sr-Latn',
  };

  // Run request
  const [response] = await translationClient.translateText(request);

  for (const translation of response.translations) {
    console.log(`Translation: ${translation.translatedText}`);
  }
}

translateText();
```

But I can not find the information anywhere about what is this "parent" parameter, how to fill it, where do I get it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

The `parent` parameter is used to tell the API what project and location will be used to process the request. For more information about the parameter see this for [reference](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects/translateText). Also you just need to uncomment the first few lines of the code and make a few changes:

```
const projectId = 'your-project-id-here'; // see https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#identifying_projects
const location = 'global'; // Do not change this as this is the default location used for Translation API
const text = 'text to translate'; // Replace "text to translate" to whatever text you want to translate to
```

Your whole code should look like:

```
/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment these variables before running the sample.
 */
const projectId = 'xxxxxxxxxx'; // your project ID that could be seen in the home page of Google Cloud Console
const location = 'global';
const text = 'Hello world'; // the text you want to translate

// Imports the Google Cloud Translation library
const {TranslationServiceClient} = require('@google-cloud/translate');

// Instantiates a client
const translationClient = new TranslationServiceClient();
async function translateText() {
  // Construct request
  const request = {
    parent: `projects/${projectId}/locations/${location}`, // get the values of projectId and location variable declared at the start of the code
    contents: [text],
    mimeType: 'text/plain', // mime types: text/plain, text/html
    sourceLanguageCode: 'en',
    targetLanguageCode: 'sr-Latn',
  };

  // Run request
  const [response] = await translationClient.translateText(request);

  for (const translation of response.translations) {
    console.log(`Translation: ${translation.translatedText}`); 
  }
}

translateText();
```

Comment: When using **global** for location I am getting this error: **Invalid location name. Project id is different from the project associated with the request.**